# Spring Data MongoDB index declaration for field of field

Tags: mongodb, indexing, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following Spring Data MongoDB document:

```
@Document(collection = "messages")
@CompoundIndexes({ @CompoundIndex(name = "chatId_messageId", def = "{'chatId': 1, 'messageId': 1}") })
public class Message implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1590112217771926691L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Long chatId;

    private Integer messageId;

    private Post post;

}
```

the `Post` model(**which is not Spring Data MongoDB document**) looks like:

```
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -886664249197573502L;

    private String id;

}
```

I'd like to add index to the `Message.post.id` field.

How it can be done with Spring Data MongoDB and `Message.post` field declaration in `Message` document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `Message.post.id` to an already compound index, then do it like

```
@Document(collection = "messages")
@CompoundIndexes({ @CompoundIndex(name = "chatId_messageId", def = "{'chatId': 1, 'messageId': 1, 'Message.post.id' : 1}") })
public class Message implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1590112217771926691L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Long chatId;

    private Integer messageId;

    private Post post;

}
```

Compound indexes are indexes that have more than one indexed field, so ideally, the most restrictive field should be to the left of the B-tree. If you want to index by sex and birth, for instance, the index should begin by birth, as it is much more restrictive than sex.

Or if you want to treat it as a saperate index, then create index using `@Indexed` like

```
    public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -886664249197573502L;

    @Indexed
    private String id;
}
```

### Updated

For more info regarding how queries with sub fields of compound index works, check [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will this index effectively work if I'll only query the documents by `Message.post.id` without `chatId` and `messageId` ?

Comment: I apologize, but it's hard to see the difference between your first and second solutions. Could you please clarify it ?

Comment: @alexanoid yes it should work. And for effective performance, the most variant field shoud be on the left side of the compound index

Comment: Thanks! I still don't understand from your second solution how to add `Message.post.id` (as the separate index) with `@Indexed` annotation? Could you please clarify it ?